# JPA, CriteriaBuilder and List

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee

let´s suppose I have following entities:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "COMPETENCY")
    public class Competency {

        @Id
        @Getter
        @Setter
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private Integer id;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "COMP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
        private Set<ProficiencyLevel> proficiencyLevels = new HashSet<ProficiencyLevel>();
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "PROFICIENCY_LEVEL")
    public class ProficiencyLevel {

        @Id
        @Getter
        @Setter
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private Integer id;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @Column(name = "LEVEL_NAME", nullable = false)
        private String levelName;
    }
```

Please note there is a 1:N relationship between Competency and ProficiencyLevel.

Is it possible to, by using CriteriaBuilder to do something like:

```
select competency.proficiencyLevels pl where pl.name like '%something%'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to select a list of `Competency` objects or `ProficiencyLevel`-s? Because your select is missing the `from` clause.

Comment: Hello, yes, I forgot, actually it is a simplification of my code. I want to select all proficiencyLevel from competency that satisfies condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select `ProficiencyLevel`s with name matching a given string, belonging to a given `Competency` object, you can do it like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ProficiencyLevel> cq = cb.createQuery(ProficiencyLevel.class);
Root<Competency> root = cq.from(Competency.class);
Join<Competency, ProficiencyLevel> join = root.join("proficiencyLevels");
cq.select(join);
cq.where(cb.equal(root, someCompetency));
cq.where(cb.like(join.get("name"), "%something%"));
TypedQuery<ProficiencyLevel> q = em.createQuery(cq);
List<ProficiencyLevel> results = q.getResultList();
```

The join would not be necessary if the `ProficiencyLevel` class contained a reference to it's `Competency` and you could use `ProficiencyLevel` as a root for the query.